# No entiendo como funcionan bien los arrays

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy teniendo dificultades para afrontar un ejercicio, que estoy haciendo es bastante sencillo pero no logro comprender.

ADJUNTO CODIGO

int cuantos  = 0;

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cuantos = cuantos + i;
        
        
    }
    int posicion=0;
    int array1[]=new int[cuantos];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        array1[posicion]=j;
        posicion=j+posicion;
        
    }
   
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
```

La cosa es que el ejercicio que estoy haciendo debe de mostrar una sequencia de numeros 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 etc... entiendo que se hace con otro bucle pero no comprendo como aplicarlo si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme. dandome pistas...

**Logre que ponga los espacios con 0 o mas bien que pinte los espacios que le tocan.**

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejercicio recalca que debes guardar en un Array un numero del `1` hasta `n` .Asimismo cada numero debe repetirse tantas veces como su valor representa osea si es 2 seria 2 2
Llevado a código

```
 int num=10;//declaramos n valores
 int cuantos = (num*(num+1))/2;//obtenemos la suma aritmética de números que hay desde 1  hasta n (gauss)

int array1[]=new int[cuantos];//declaras el array que contendra todos los valores
int posicion=0;
```

> el primero for ira de 1 hasta n y esta representado por la variable `i`

> el segundo for se repetirá tantas veces como el valor de `i` represente

> la posición ira en aumento progresivamente es decir no depende de ni de `i` ni `j`
> como ya hallamos la suma aritmética sabemos que se llenara completamente evitando un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            array1[posicion]=i;
            posicion++;
       }
    
    }
```